# Split linux files based on condition

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file in `linux`. The contents of the file are below.

```
Test_12
Test_abc
start_1
start_abcd
end_123
end_abcde_12
```

Now I want to split the file into multiple small files based on matching string that comes after the first `underscore`

Ouput:

- Test.txt:

  ```
  Test_12
  Test_abc
  ```
- start.txt:

  ```
  start_1
  start_abcd
  ```
- end.txt:

  ```
  end_123
  end_abcde_12
  ```

I have tried like below

```
while read -r line ; do
    echo "$line" >> "${line}.txt"  
done < split.txt
```

But I got files for each line.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I get my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trim the underscore and trailing text from each line. `%%_*` does that:

```
while read -r line ; do
    echo "$line" >> "${line%%_*}.txt"  
done < split.txt
```

Explanation:

- `%`: trim trailing text
- `%%`: find the longest possible match
- `_*`: an underscore and everything after

Comment: That would strip all leading and trailing white space off each line which might not be what the OP expects (esp the trailing spaces). Always set `IFS=` on a read unless you have a specific objective in mind that you need to leave it set for. It will also be an order of magnitude slower than an equivalent awk script and will produce different output depending on which version of `echo` is in your path. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 2):

Better to use awk for this:

```
awk -F_ 'p && $1 != p{close(fn)} {p=$1; fn=p ".txt"; print>>fn} END{close(fn)}' split.txt
```

There is little bit of extra handling to close the files when value in first column changes so that we don't have too many open files if your input file is huge.

Comment: I might be misreading it but I don't think $1 can ever be equal to fn. You don't need to close() in the END, btw - awk does that by default.

Answer (score 0):

Read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and then just use awk.

With GNU awk all you need is:

```
awk -F'_' '{print > ($1".txt")}' file
```

Otherwise with other awks, if your input file is grouped by the first field as shown in your question then all you need is:

```
awk -F'_' '{f=$1".txt"; print > f} f!=p{close(p); p=f}' file
```

and if it isn't then it's just slightly less efficient as you may need to re-open a file that was previously closed (hence the `>>` instead of `>`):

```
awk -F'_' '{f=$1".txt"; print >> f} f!=p{close(p); p=f}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
while read line; do
    content=`echo $line|awk 'BEGIN{FS="_"}{print $1}'`
    for f in *; do
        filename=`echo $f|awk 'BEGIN{FS="."}{print $1}'`
        if [ "$content" == "$filename" ]; then
            echo $line>>$f
            break
        else
            echo $line>>$content.txt
            break
        fi
    done
done< file.txt
```

Output:

```
bash-4.4$ ls -lrt
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 21726 21726 978 Sep 22 04:54 README.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 21726 21726  49 Sep 22 04:56 file.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 21726 21726 252 Sep 22 05:06 script.sh
bash-4.4$ cat file.txt
Test_12
Test_abc
Start_1
Start_abc
end_1
end_abc
bash-4.4$ ./script.sh
bash-4.4$ ls -lrt
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 21726 21726 978 Sep 22 04:54 README.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 21726 21726  49 Sep 22 04:56 file.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 21726 21726 252 Sep 22 05:06 script.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 21726 21726  17 Sep 22 05:06 Test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 21726 21726  18 Sep 22 05:06 Start.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 21726 21726  14 Sep 22 05:06 end.txt
bash-4.4$ cat Start.txt
Start_1
Start_abc
bash-4.4$ cat Test.txt
Test_12
Test_abc
bash-4.4$ cat end.txt
end_1
end_abc
```